# How to access status in ansible_facts.services?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to Stop and/or Disable a systemd service if it is running and/or enabled on the remote host.

Contents of tasks/main.yml:

```
---
- name: Populate service facts
  service_facts:

- name: Display selected service
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services[serviceToDisplay]
  loop: "{{ disable_services }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: serviceToDisplay
  vars:
    disable_services:
      - cups.service
      - cups

- name: Stop and Disable service if it is running or enabled
  systemd:
    name: cups.service
    enabled: false
    state: stopped
  when:
    - "serviceToDisable is defined"
    - "serviceToDisable.status == 'enabled'"
  loop: "{{ disable_services }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: serviceToDisable
  vars:
    disable_services:
      - cups.service
      - cups
  become: true
...
```

Results:

```
PLAY [configServerGroup] *************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [radicale.jlhimpel.net]

TASK [example : Populate service facts] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [radicale.jlhimpel.net]

TASK [example : Display selected service] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [radicale.jlhimpel.net] => (item=cups.service) => {
    "ansible_facts.services[serviceToDisplay]": {
        "name": "cups.service",
        "source": "systemd",
        "state": "running",
        "status": "enabled"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "serviceToDisplay",
    "serviceToDisplay": "cups.service"
}
ok: [radicale.jlhimpel.net] => (item=cups) => {
    "ansible_facts.services[serviceToDisplay]": {
        "name": "cups",
        "source": "sysv",
        "state": "running"
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "serviceToDisplay",
    "serviceToDisplay": "cups"
}

TASK [example : Stop and Disable service if it is running or enabled] ****************************************************************************************
fatal: [radicale.jlhimpel.net]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'serviceToDisable.status == 'enabled'' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (serviceToDisable.status == 'enabled'): 'str object' has no attribute 'status'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/jwhimpel/ansible/roles/example/tasks/main.yml': line 16, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Stop and Disable service if it is running or enabled\n  ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
radicale.jlhimpel.net      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Ansible version: 2.9.14-1.fc32 on Fedora

How should I go about checking if the status == enabled or the state == running?

Note: The service may optionally not be present in ansible_facts.service.  It may also optionally not be running and/or not enabled.  I am attempting to make the tasks idempotent.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second task should be as below, please notice the `name` clause and the `when` section:

```yaml
  - name: Stop and Disable service if it is running or enabled
    systemd:
      name: "{{ ansible_facts.services[serviceToDisable]['name'] }}"
      enabled: false
      state: stopped
    when:
      - serviceToDisable is defined
      - ansible_facts.services[serviceToDisable]['status'] == 'enabled'
    loop: "{{ disable_services }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: serviceToDisable
    vars:
      disable_services:
        - cups.service
        - cups
    become: true
```

Not sure why you have defined two times the same service (`cups.service` and `cups`), but I guess you have your good reasons.